# SharedPreferences в Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, архитектура, android-shared-preferences

Как всё-таки правильнее организовать логику работы с `SharedPreferences` в Clean Architecture? Ведь будет плохо обращаться к сохраненным данным отовсюду, это повлечет расходы времени и нервов когда нужно будет что-то поменять. Если же написать для этого **всего один класс**, то будет "чисто". В таком классе явно будут храниться приватные ключи и публичные геттеры/сейверы для данных.

---

*Способ 1*

Давайте попробуем создать его где-нибудь, а потом <s>забыть где</s> обращаться к нему отовсюду. Самое тупое что приходит в голову, это сохранить его в кастомном классе, наследованном от `Application`:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Prefs prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        prefs = new Prefs(this);
    }

    public static Prefs getPrefs() {
        return prefs;
    }
}
```

Ну а класс `Prefs` написать примерно так:

```
public class Prefs {

    private static final String COINS = "coins";

    private SharedPreferences sp;

    public Prefs (Context context) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
    }

    public long getCoins() {
        return sp.getLong(COINS, 0);
    }

    public void saveCoins(long coins) {
        sp.edit().putLong(COINS, coins).apply();
    }
}
```

Способ вполне себе хороший, все логично: приложение (`App`) содержит настройки (`Prefs`), но не очень нравится, что каждое обращение к `Prefs` проходит через `App`.

---

*Способ 2*

Инициализируем `Prefs` и пусть живет своей природой

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Prefs.init(this);
    }
}
```

Ну и как он выглядит:

```
public class Prefs {

    private static final String COINS = "coins";

    private static SharedPreferences sp;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
    }

    public static long getCoins() {
        return sp.getLong(COINS, 0);
    }

    public static void saveCoins(long coins) {
        sp.edit().putLong(COINS, coins).apply();
    }
}
```

Теперь можно не трогать App и обращаться к Prefs отовсюду напрямую и, причем, не передавая контекста.

- Какой вариант лучше для Clean Architecture?
- Логично ли разместить Prefs в com.example.app.data?

Comment: 1. В данном случае, будет намного чище, если  инжектить данную модель  с помощью `Dagger2`.



2. Да, `data` - слой отлично подходит в Вашем случае. Но я обычно в таких случаях делаю отдельную модель под каждую сущность и называю её с припиской `manager`. (В ней делаются запросы в бд или преф), и данная модель инжектится в `Repository`

Comment: Почему отдельную сущность, `Clean` должен соблюдать все парадигмы из `SOLID`, и в данном случае, `SRP` (принцип единой ответственности) - одна из них.

Comment: @nonews, пока что в пакете data тогда оставлю, позже попробую научиться использовать Dagger2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В данном случае, будет намного чище, если инжектить данную модель с помощью `Dagger2`.
2. Да, `data` - слой отлично подходит в Вашем случае. Но я обычно в таких случаях делаю отдельную модель под каждую сущность и называю её с припиской `manager`. (В ней делаются запросы в бд или преф), и данная модель инжектится в `Repository`

**Почему отдельная сущность**

Clean должен соблюдать все парадигмы из `SOLID`, и в данном случае, `SRP` (принцип единой ответственности) - одна из них.